# Нужно уменьшить width для -webkit-scrollbar-thumb

Tags: html, css, background, scrollbar

Здравстуйте!Имею проблемку, нужно задать width для -webkit-scrollbar-thumb, как на макете, 80px. Возможно, как-то через градиент, но как тогда сделать закругленние края?Имею такой код:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: #e77d7d;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Вот тут хорошо описано, как такое сделать: https://active-vision.ru/blog/polosa-prokrutki-css/